Why does my toilet have a weak flush when there's a long time between flushes?
EDIT: The toilet is a 15-year old major US brand 1.6 gpf toilet with a flapper flush valve; but during this troubleshooting I have replaced the OEM flush valve with another major brand's elegant canister-style flush valve, and the identical problem persisted. It's not the flush valve.  No canister upgrade was available from the OEM.
EDIT2: Here's another little factoid. I thought maybe the original fill valve may have been implicated.  I noticed swirling water in the filling tank immediately following the flush-handle being depressed, and that swirling current gave the flapper some "lift". I thought maybe the flapper "loft" was insufficient. So I replaced the fill valve with a new one, same mfgr, same part. But the problem persisted. Also, see edit above. However,  what I note now is that when a flush succeeds, there's always a tiny "chihhhh" sound from the fill valve when the handle is pressed and water begins to exit the tank causing the valve's float to drop; When the flush fails, that sound doesn't happen.
EDIT3: When I put the bathroom in 15 years ago, I installed a stainless steel (decorative) water-hammer arrester on the toilet supply line. No problem for 15 years. But I thought I should mention it.
ORIGINAL:
I don't understand these symptoms:  I can do half a dozen test flushes, with nothing in the bowl but water, one right after the other, waiting for the tank to fill each time, and they succeed fine.  I'll then wait a half hour. House is empty but for me--nobody using the toilet.  I'll go back to it, check inside the tank that the water level is still at the mark I made, and  look in the bowl and the water level seems at the usual bowl level,  and do another test flush.  Now, on this flush, no eddy forms; the bowl water level rises somewhat. Failed flush. Wait for the tank to fill again. Flush. Success.
I figure the half dozen test flushes, one right after the other, would not have succeeded if any of these things was true:

the rim-jets were clogged
there was a clog in the toilet trap
the vent was blocked
the flush valve needed adjustment

So, something mysterious is happening when time elapses.

Would help if we knew something about your hardware. Please post brand, etc. or a photo.

I don't mention any brands online ever since my neighbor got sued for a negative online review of a product. He's a scientist and the product's marketing claims were bogus. Nonetheless he's out a lof of money defending himself.  A so-called SLAPP suit.

But I can mention that it's a well-known brand in the US.

Pull off the tank lid and inspect the float. Does the tank consistently overfill to the siphon after a flush?

@AdamO I replaced the fill valve with an identical OEM new one just in case the fill valve was implicated.  Tank always fills to the mark I placed, which was where a proper flush filled to for some years now.  An additional factoid: this problem coincided with a pressure regulator in the basement that brought  mains pressure from 80psi down to 70psi. Advice I got here at DIY was that the mains pressure is irrelevant, but I've since bumped it up to 75psi. Next step will be a vinegar soak overnight, though it seems that shouldn't be necessary.

Could have to do with water not reaching critical mass in the P-trap, maybe a recent clog or something. Something drains over time, then 1 flush, 2 flush the second flush gets it over the top. How many days or weeks since the problem started.

@SushiGuy Since the "solution" is to flush again it's not been a critical problem but it's been going on for a few months -- after working fine for years.  There's another toilet further downstream on the same vent -- and there has been one there for years too. If there was a venting issue we would have encountered it long ago.  I will do a vinegar soak this weekend in case the jets aren't working optimally.

Going online and saying brand X is garbage and their claims are false is much different than saying you have a problem after years of good use and asking for help to fix.

@crip659  I do see the difference. I just don't want to mention brands for my own peace of mind.

I've swapped out the OEM flapper valve with another manufacturer's elegant canister style flush valve and the problem persisted: a half dozen perfect flushes right in a row, time elapses, and the next flush fails. First flush in the morning fails even though the tank is full.  The only persistent pieces of equipment are the OEM fill valve, the original and the new one (same brand, same part) that I replaced it with, and, of course, the porcelain unit itself.

I had one that offered an especially weak flush every once in a while. I never did figure out what the reason for that was and ended up replacing the toilet a couple weeks ago for an unrelated reason.
